# Escape character error in switch case

Tags: switch-statement

When I am passing a string in the loop using a switch case statement, it provides me the following error.

```
1 x     X 00
1
java.lang.RuntimeException: INVALID VALUE
    at test.main(test.java:28)
```

While debugging, I figure out the exception is thrown after the "x " in the string where lies the escape character. I am confused why this is happening, shouldn't it ignore the escape character and s.charAt(i) should move on to the next char?

```
public class test{

  public static void main(String [] args){

    String s = "1 x \tX 00";

    System.out.println(s);

    for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
      switch(s.charAt(i)){

        case '0':
          System.out.println("0");
          break;
        case '1':
          System.out.println("1");
          break;
        case 'X':
          System.out.println("X");
          break;
        case 'x':
          System.out.println("X");
          break;

        default: throw new RuntimeException("INVALID VALUE");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the escape character. Your for-loop runs over every character in the string `s`. So that includes the spaces and the tabs.

If you run through your string, the first character, `s.charAt(0)` will be `'1'`. This is one of the cases of your switch statement. However, the next character in your string, `s.charAt(1)`, is simply a space `' '`. There is nothing for a space in your switch statement, thus it goes to the default case and throws the exception you defined there.

You seem to be confusing the looping through the string with `scanf("%c", &var)` from C maybe?

In any case, white space will not be ignored as your for-loop really runs over every character in the string `s`. You'll manually have to make cases for the white spaces to ignore those. For example:

```
case ' ':
case '\t':
case '\n':
case '\r':
  break;
```